Trigger an internal API while creating superset users
Am trying to save the usernames of the superset users in my internal application DB as well for my custom logic, so when the newly users get created from the superset, i want to trigger my internal application API, where i can update the username in my internal application DB, am not sure where to trigger my internal API i tried finding it, by tracing out the API
/users/add but cant get any realted code on apache superset code, so does anyone have any idea where the user details stored code is written in superset apache so i can call my API there
